# Julia's DifferentialEquations package fails when using fortran-wrapped right-hand-side

Tags: julia, jit, differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a system of ordinary differential equations with Julia's `DifferentialEquations` method. The right-hand-side of my ODEs is wrapped [Fortran 90](https://github.com/Nicholaswogan/ImpactAtmosphere/blob/0cbca65175a65cb0038e900b4823718fba5009bf/src/EvolveAtmFort.f90#L335). Here is my Julia code:

```
using DifferentialEquations
function rhs(dNdt,N,p,t)
    ccall((:__atmos_MOD_rhs, "./EvolveAtmFort.so"), Cvoid,(Ref{Float64}, Ref{Float64},Ref{Float64}),t,N,dNdt)
end

N0 = [0.0,298.9,0.0562,22.9,0.0166,35.96,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]*6.022e23
tspan = [0.0,1.0e6*365.0*24.0*60.0*60.0]
prob = ODEProblem(rhs,N0,tspan)
sol = solve(prob,Rodas5());
```

This produces the following long error, that has to do with calculating the derivative/jacobian of the right-hand-side. Below, I only include some portions of the `Stacktrace` that seem important.

```
MethodError: no method matching Float64(::ForwardDiff.Dual{ForwardDiff.Tag{DiffEqBase.TimeGradientWrapper{ODEFunction{true,typeof(rhs),LinearAlgebra.UniformScaling{Bool},Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing},Array{Float64,1},DiffEqBase.NullParameters},Float64},Float64,1})
Closest candidates are:
  Float64(::Real, !Matched::RoundingMode) where T<:AbstractFloat at rounding.jl:200
  Float64(::T) where T<:Number at boot.jl:715
  Float64(!Matched::Int8) at float.jl:60
  ...

Stacktrace:
[1] convert(::Type{Float64},...
[2] Base.RefValue{Float64}...
[3] convert(::Type{Ref{Float64}}, ...
[4] cconvert(::Type{T} where T, 
[5] rhs(::Array{ForwardDiff.Dual{ForwardDiff.Tag{DiffEqBase.TimeGradientWrapper{...
[6] (::ODEFunction{true,typeof(rhs),LinearAlgebra...
[7] (::DiffEqBase.TimeGradientWrapper{ODEFunction{true,typeof(rhs),LinearAlgebra...
[8] derivative!(::Array{Float64,1},...
[9] calc_tderivative!(::OrdinaryDiffEq...
[10] calc_rosenbrock_differentiation! at...
[etc...]
```

When I use a jacobian-free method, like `Tsit5()`, the integration works just fine. Only methods that require jacobian calculations fail. What am I doing wrong? How can I adjust my Fortran wrapper so that I can use implicit methods? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to the implicit automatic differentiation in some implicit solvers. You'll need to turn that off, i.e. `Rodas5(autodiff=false)`.